# Initialization error: Cannot use instance member within property initializer before self is available

Tags: swift, variables

```
let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
let IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS  = screenSize < 568.0
```

"Cannot use instance member within property initializer before self is available" this is the error am getting when executing the code.

Comment: Please [search on the error](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+Cannot+use+instance+member+within+property+initializer+before+self+is+available) before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Constants refer to fixed values that a program may not alter during its execution. `IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS`  is a constant hence it need the fix value at the time of initialisation of a class hence the error. In your case its computing the value based on the screen height so you can declare it as a computed property like below

```
 class Constants: NSObject {
    let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
    var IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS: Bool {
        return screenSize < 568
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

you need to create constant with `static`

```
static  let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
static let IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS  = screenSize < 568.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this way to check which iPhone you are using :

```
struct ScreenSize{

    static let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
    static let height = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
    static let maxLength = max(ScreenSize.width, ScreenSize.height)
    static let minLength = min(ScreenSize.width, ScreenSize.height)
    static let scale = UIScreen.main.scale
    static let ratio1619 = (0.5625 * ScreenSize.width)
}

struct DeviceType{

   static let isIphone4orLess =  UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && ScreenSize.maxLength < 568.0
    static let isIPhone5 = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && ScreenSize.maxLength == 568.0
    static let isIPhone6 = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && ScreenSize.maxLength == 667.0
    static let isIPhone6p = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && ScreenSize.maxLength == 736.0
}
```

then use this as :

```
if DeviceType.isIPhone5 {
    //Do iPhone 5 Stuff
}
```

Comment: Please don't ever do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use any instance variable while initialising the property instead of that you should use below code.

```
class constant : NSObject {
let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
var IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS = false
override init() {
    IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS  = screenSize < 568.0
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift uses two-phase initialization for it's variables.

> Class initialization in Swift is a two-phase process. In the first
>   phase, each stored property is assigned an initial value by the class
>   that introduced it. Once the initial state for every stored property
>   has been determined, the second phase begins, and each class is given
>   the opportunity to customize its stored properties further before the
>   new instance is considered ready for use.

So you cannot access instance variables before you intitialize them. You can use a `getter` for this variable Try using this

```
let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
var IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS :Bool{
    get{
        return screenSize < 568.0
    }
}
```